# How does variable swapping work internally?

Tags: python

Simple and short question. Swapping two variables in Python is very easy: `a, b = b, a`. That's ok, I have no objections :) But I'm interested how it works internally? Does it create some temporary variable by itself or it is something more interesting (I bet so)?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Python source code is converted to [bytecode](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-bytecode) before it is executed. You can see how the swap works internally by using the disassembler `dis` to see what the bytecode looks like:

```
import dis
>>> def f(a,b): a, b = b, a
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              6 ROT_TWO             
              7 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

In simple terms, it pushes the values of a and b on the stack, rotates (swaps) the top two elements, then pops the values again.

See also:

- [Python Bytecode Instructions](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html#python-bytecode-instructions)

Comment: Great. I had wrong thought that when we use `,` between two o more expressions , Python will pack them into a (here _temporary_) "tuple". Maybe this isn't the case here because on the left hand side there is exactly these two `a` and `b`. Is that the reason there is no `BUILD_TUPLE` in instructions?

Comment: @S.B yes this is a special case, optimized by Python. In general, a `,` will create a tuple.