# Does this way of swapping values in list use extra memory in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, swap

The usual way to swap values in a list is to use a temporary variable.

```
temp = l[i]
l[i] = l[j]
l[j] = temp
```

But in python you can do this:

```
l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]
```

How does this second method work? Is it the exact same process? Does it use less / more memory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does variable swapping work internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587236/how-does-variable-swapping-work-internally)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import dis


def swap_using_temp(a, b):
    temp = a
    a = b
    b = temp


def swap_using_unpacking(a, b):
    a, b = b, a
```

`swap_using_unpacking` does not require extra memory.

**Explanation:**
If you disassemble the code using [**`dis`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#module-dis) module of both the function described then you will see that in `swap_using_unpacking` there is a bytecode instruction [**`ROT_TWO`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-ROT_TWO) which swaps the 2 topmost elements of the stack(which don't require a third variable hence no extra memory is consumed).

---

```
dis.dis(swap_using_unpacking)

 11           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              4 ROT_TWO
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              8 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

```
dis.dis(swap_using_temp)

  5           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 STORE_FAST               2 (temp)

  6           4 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  7           8 LOAD_FAST                2 (temp)
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Great. I had wrong thought that when we use `,` between two o more expressions , Python will pack them into a (here _temporary_) `tuple`.  Maybe this isn't the case here because on the left hand side there is exactly these two `a` and `b`. Is that the reason there is no `BUILD_TUPLE` in instructions?

Answer (score 2):

You are asking the wrong question here. You are not using assembly language but Python, so you should not worry for some extra bytes. What really matters in Python is readability.

Anyway, both versions should be internally implemented more or less the same way, except that the first one creates an additional identifier. It is explicitely named `temp` so *provided you do not use it in that scope*, it brings no real problem.

If you use a *linting* environment that warns you for possible problems (what you should do...) you must be aware that reusing a variable name that hides the same name in an outer scope, while perfectly correct on a language point of view will light some warning on. But as you should not use a `temp` identifier outside a local scope (readability...) it should not be a problem either.

So it is more of a *matter of taste*. If you or your team mates often use other languages that do not allow multiple assignments the first way will be more *natural*. If you mainly use Python, the second way is IMHO more *pythonic* because it avoids adding an unnecessary identifier in the local scope. But as I have already said, nothing more that a matter of taste...