# Swap values of variables

Tags: python

Good day,

Could you please explain in what order the code executes.

```
variable_1 = 1
variable_2 = 2

variable_1, variable_2 = variable_2, variable_1
```

Why is the output 2,1 and not 2,2?
Isn't variable_1 already become of value 2?

Comment: Does this clears your doubt ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587236/how-does-variable-swapping-work-internally

Comment: Thank you Vimalan and Mahesh, very informative